# Opening symbolic link in kernel Windows8.1+

Tags: file, kernel, driver, device, symlink

i'm trying to open symbolic link as a file using `ZwOpenProcess` in kernel space. Using code below all is ok on XP-7. But using Windows 8.1 `ZwOpenProcess` fails with different NTSTATUS codes, like `0xC0000001`, `0xC000000D`

```
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  ObjectAttributes;
HANDLE             FileHandle;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK    IoStatus;
NTSTATUS           Status;

InitializeObjectAttributes ( &ObjectAttributes,
                             SymLinkOrDeviceName, // <--- \Device\CEDRIVER60
                             OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE,
                             (HANDLE) NULL,
                             (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) NULL );

Status = ZwOpenFile ( &FileHandle,
                      FILE_READ_ACCESS,
                      &ObjectAttributes,
                      &IoStatus,
                      0,
                      FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE );


if ( !NT_SUCCESS ( Status ) )
{
    DbgPrint("TEST: ERROR %p ", Status); // <--- 0xC0000001, 0xC000000D
    goto Exit;
}
```

I checked, using WinObj - symbolic link present in system, code works fine on XP-7.

I also trind to change Access to - FILE_ANY_ACCESS - the same result.

Comment: in general code is correct, but error code can return not IO subsystem but driver. i do not know specific of driver who create CEDRIVER60 - possible it require special parameters on create (like file path, EA, etc). when you use FILE_ANY_ACCESS - here already IO subsytem must return error to you. and i do not understand how is ZwOpenProcess and symlink related here ??

Answer (score 0):

> ZwOpenProcess

I suppose you meant ZwOpenFile.

> \Device\CEDRIVER60

Did you really looked into the \Device directory? This directory usually contains device objects created by drivers. Symbolic links are usually placed into directories like \DosDevices. You should also include the OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE flag.

> FILE_READ_ACCESS

This flag determines access right(s) required to successfully deliver an IOCTL message to a target device object. Specify a true file access right constant like FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_READ_DATA (its value is actually the same as FILE_READ_ACCESS) or GENERIC_READ. MSDN page on ZwOpenFile (and ZwCreateFile) is also worth of reading. You may need to include the SYNCHRONIZE flag too.

> %p

NTSTATUS is defined as long (32-bit signed integer). %x is more appropriate.

Comment: in general all this is true, but not explain concrete error. if this device not exist - error will be c0000034. faster of all this error codes returned by driver, not by IO subsystem

Comment: @RbMm: I know the codes comes from the driver. I am not familiar with taht driver. Maybe, it just does not like FILE_READ_DATA access rights or does some other checks when receiving the IRP_MJ_CREATE packet.

Comment: yes, i and assume that this is error driver specific, but not from windows IO subsystem. really error can be or from IO subsystem or from driver code. i sure that second variant

Comment: I suspect the latter case too.